# Problem with strings containing " " in Stream.Publish, Android, Facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to post on facebook wall through my adapted FBConnect (something similar to this http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/android/845/) and I'm having a issue with strings that contain ""

```
public void postToWall(String message){
     Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
     parameters.putString("message", message);

     String attachment;

     if (website == null) {
      attachment = "{\"name\":\""+ name + "\"," +
   "\"description\":\""+ description + "\"" +       
   "}";
     }
     else {
      attachment = "{\"name\":\""+ name + "\"," +
       "\"href\":\"" + website + "\"," +
       "\"description\":\""+ description + "\"" +       
       "}";
     }
     parameters.putString("attachment", attachment);
```

E.G. if description is 'lorem ipsum' it works quite fine but for instance if description is 'lorem ipsum "blhe" bazooka' than it doesn't work.

I already tried to encode the attachment this way

```
parameters.putString("attachment", URLEncoder.encode(attachment));
```

but I get the same result.
EDIT: actually with URLEncoder it doesn't work at all..

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `escapeHtml` from apache commons lang: http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml%28java.io.Writer,%20java.lang.String%29
and apply that method to all variables that possibly can contain unwanted characters.

`attachment = "{\"name\":\""+ StringEcapeUtils.escapeHtml(name) + "\"," +
   "\"description\":\""+ StringEcapeUtils.escapeHtml(description) + "\"" +

   "}";`